# How can I send Shift + Lbutton click event to other process?

Tags: mfc, keyboard, mouse, message

I want send shift + Button click event to other process.

I used SendNotifyMessage like this.

```
while(1)
{

  if( g_bSendEvent )
  {
     sleep(1000);

     if( g_dwSubStatus == 0 )
     {
        SendNotifyMessage(g_hWndMain, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_LSHIFT, 0);
        SendNotifyMessage(g_hWndMain, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, g_lClickPos);

        g_dwSubStatus = 1;
      }
      else if( g_dwSubStatus == 1 )
      {
        SendNotifyMessage(g_hWndMain, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, g_lClickPos);
        SendNotifyMessage(g_hWndMain, WM_KEYUP, VK_LSHIFT, 0);
      }
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work.

Button Click Event was send to other process.

Please help.

Tool: VS 2008 , MFC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use messages! The [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function is what you are looking for. (Remember that your process needs to be elevated if you want to send input to another elevated process.)